# apache fop embedded png is not rendering

Tags: apache-fop

i have trouble with embedding images in my pdf (it worked 2 years ago, but now it fails)

Dependencies are there:

```
    implementation("org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.9")
    implementation("org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:2.9")
```

the PNG file is also valid, but for some reason i still get

**The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for data:image/png;base64**

The full config is here:
https://github.com/Black-Forrest-Development/open-event/blob/development/src/main/resources/fop/fop.xconf

The template (which is preprocessed by velocity) is here
https://github.com/Black-Forrest-Development/open-event/blob/development/src/main/resources/fop/event1.vm

And the usage is here

https://github.com/Black-Forrest-Development/open-event/blob/development/src/main/kotlin/de/sambalmueslie/openevent/core/logic/export/EventPdfExporter.kt

i have no idea whats wrong.
I debugged a little and figured out, that even when the file has the correct PNG-Signature
the PreloaderRawPNG fails, cause its input stream is pointing to the fop.xconf file which is of course no png file.

I debugged with that file: https://open.psm.church/assets/img/logo.png

It also fails if i embedd the base64  encoded png directly.

Any ideas?

Regards
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake

I called the `public static FopFactory newInstance(final URI baseURI)` instead of the `public static FopFactory newInstance(File fopConf)`

after changing it to

```
    private val config = loader.getResource("classpath:fop/fop.xconf").getOrNull()!!
    private val fopFactory: FopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(File(config.toURI()))
```

it worked.